# How to buy I bond for child and spouse?

Tags: united-states, bonds, government-bonds, bond-funds

To purchase `I bond` I followed the steps below:

1. Opened TreasuryDirect account using my SSN and other information.
2. Purchased a `I Bond` under my registration.
3. Created a new `Primary Owner` registration along with my spouse as `My Name WITH My Spouse` So I am the primary owner and spouse is secondary owner.
4. Re-assigned my I Bond's registration to  `My Name WITH My Spouse`
5. Then I established a minor account for my child under My account (As a linked account).

Questions:

1. When I buy `I Bond` for my child, can I buy with new `Primary Owner` registration? Like `Childs Name WITH My Name`. So my child will be primary owner and I will be secondary owner.
2. How do I purchase `I Bond` for my spouse through my account. (not as Gift) Does spouse need a separate Treasury Direct account?
3. Can spouse buy `I Bond` using Primary Owner registration? So spouse will be primary owner and I will be second owner.